# Referring to figures other than with "as depicted in"

Tags: synonyms, science, reference

I’m currently writing my first English scientific paper and am repeatedly using *as depicted in* when referring to a figure or table in the text.

Can you tell me some alternatives to that phrase?

Comment: As shown in, as represented in.

Comment: Many times, you don't have to say it at all. You could make a statement, then simply follow it with (Table "X"/ Figure "X"). *Germination rates were significantly higher after 24 h in running water than in controls (Fig. 4).*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some examples:

...as shown in Fig. X
...as seen in Fig. X  (or ...as can be seen in Fig. X)
...which is evident in Fig. X
Fig. X shows...

The data in Table X indicates that ...

If you have some certainty where the figure or table will be relative to the text, you can use phrases such as:

...as seen in the figure to the left... (to the right, on the previous page, etc.) The next table shows blah blah ...

Hope that helps.